# Reference-request: Closed form of $\int_0^1 (-\operatorname{W_0}(-\tfrac t{\mathrm{e}}))^x \, dt$

Tags: integration, reference-request, definition, gamma-function, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

This question is the "cousin" of
[a closely related one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518920/122782).

For $x\ge0$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (-\Wp(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x \, dt
&=\frac {1+\e\,x\,(\Gamma(x+2,1)-\Gamma(x+2))}{x+1}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\int_0^1 (-\Wm(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x \, dt
&=\frac{\e\,x\Gamma(x+2,1)+1}{x+1}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
\int_0^1 (-\Wm(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x-(-\Wp(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x \, dt
&=\e\,x\,\Gamma(x+1) 
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

where $\Wp,\ \Wm$ are the real branches of the Lambert $\W$ function.

Equation \eqref{3} also suggests 
an elegant definition of the gamma function
in terms of 
the real branches of the Lambert $\W$ function as
\begin{align}
\Gamma(x+1)
&=
\frac1{\e\,x}\int_0^1 (-\Wm(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x-(-\Wp(-\tfrac t{\e}))^x \, dt
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Question: Are these relations known? Any reference?

$\endgroup$

Comment: Where are all these interesting integrals involving the Lambert W function you keep asking coming from?

Comment: @omegadot:
Out of curiosity and a strong impression
that the importance of the Lambert W function is highly underestimated.